# laravel blade @yield inside js

Tags: laravel, matomo, laravel-blade

Hi im trying to use blade to create a dynamic tracking code for my website. 
this is what i have so far i tried yielding straight to the piwikTracker var but got all sorts of errors passing it as a var seems to be working but im now not getting any stats on the backend

```
 <!-- Piwik --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var track =  @yield('track');
var pkBaseURL = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://centralcoastwindowcleaners.com.au/track/" : "http://centralcoastwindowcleaners.com.au/track/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + pkBaseURL + "piwik.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script><script type="text/javascript">
try {
var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker(pkBaseURL + "piwik.php", track);
piwikTracker.trackPageView();
piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();
} catch( err ) {}
</script><noscript><p><img src="http://centralcoastwindowcleaners.com.au/track/piwik.php?         idsite=@yield('track')" style="border:0" alt="" /></p></noscript>
<!-- End Piwik Tracking Code -->
```

is there a way i can escape it and do something like:

```
<!-- Piwik --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var pkBaseURL = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://centralcoastwindowcleaners.com.au/track/" : "http://centralcoastwindowcleaners.com.au/track/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + pkBaseURL + "piwik.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script><script type="text/javascript">
try {
var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker(pkBaseURL + "piwik.php", @yield('track'));
piwikTracker.trackPageView();
piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();
} catch( err ) {}
</script><noscript><p><img src="http://centralcoastwindowcleaners.com.au/track/piwik.php?         idsite=@yield('track')" style="border:0" alt="" /></p></noscript>
<!-- End Piwik Tracking Code -->
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think that Blade's @ functions are supposed to be placed at the beginning of a line. I could be wrong, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Also, please could you show us some of the errors that you see, by editing your question?

Comment: I assume you configured your layouts, normal views uncorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

In the context that you are showing you are not needing to yield a section, just a variable or string. This way you just pass  this would just be

```
var track =  {{$track}};
```

Sections are helpful for nested and partial views but overkill (as well as not designed) for single variables. If for some reason you cannot store and pass $track, then pass the entire line with the yield rather than just the variable.

```
//var track = 'varYouArePassing';
@yield('track');
```